# Coloring each grid cell extJS4

Tags: extjs4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color legend for grid panel in ExtJS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767469/color-legend-for-grid-panel-in-extjs4)

I have a requirement which states that each cell in the grid can take any color out of available 8 colors based on some criteria. To implement this I have used "renderer" function in column and set tdCls of meta property to css class, but its not working. Can someone help me to resolve this.

Please find sample code below.

/** View class which contains grid panel*/

```
Ext.define('xxx.xxx.TestView', {
extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',

  columns:[{
    header:'A', 
    dataIndex:'a', 
    flex:1,
    //rendering function here
    renderer:function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {       
       var cssClass = 'norepl';
       if(value != null && value != ' ') {
             var t = record.get('xxx');
             t = (t.substr(2,t.indexOf('-')-2))%8;
             cssClass = "replgrp"+t;
       }
       metaData.tdCls += cssClass; //attaching css property to tdCls of meta
       return value;
     }   
  }    
});
```

/** available 8 css classes for coloring*/

```
.replgrp0 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: #f0f6ff;
color: #09d6ff;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp1 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(255, 183, 189, 0.22);
color: #900;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp2 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: #e2ffe2;
color: #090;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp3 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(255, 233, 228, 0.12);
color: #99890e;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp4 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(186, 242, 250, 0.10);
color: #1a4f99;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp5 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(255, 242, 239, 0.23);
color: #ff7f00;
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp6 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(228, 224, 255, 0.7);
color: rgba(29, 7, 255, 0.60);
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.replgrp7 .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgba(255, 233, 228, 0.32);
color: rgba(255, 22, 12, 0.65);
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}


.norepl .x-grid-cell {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
border-left: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
border-right: 1px dotted rgba(2, 3, 3, 0.27);
}
```

Thanks and Regards,
Nari

Comment: Setting tdCls should be enough. Have you tried `metaData.tdCls = cssClass` or adding a space like so: `metaData.tdCls += ' ' + cssClass`?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall doing something like

```
 renderer:function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
 if(value != null && value != ' ') {
         var t = record.get('xxx');
         t = (t.substr(2,t.indexOf('-')-2))%8;
         cssClass = "replgrp"+t;
         value="<div class="+cssClass+">"+value+"</div>
   }
  return value;
```

This is probably the wrong way to do it though :)

Comment: Thanks :). I got the solution but not sure if it is right one.      The css class must be ".replgrp0 **.x-grid-cell-inner**"

Comment: @Nari please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if this works for you.